# I'm getting empty errors Unity 2019.2.14f1 Windows 10

Tags: unity

A week ago I was editing a script in my Unity Project with VSCode(I normally work in Visual Studio) and saved it. As soon as I saved it 4 blank errors popped up. Since then I've tried everything to get rid of them but to little avail. Please, help me.

I've already done a lot of searching and the main thing that comes up is to switch my scripting runtime to .Net 3.5. But in Unity 2019.2.14f1 the version I'm using this is no longer supported. They are also talking about Windows 7 but I'm on Windows 10.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/four-blank-errors-in-each-new-project.599980/

I tried to delete the meta of all script files but that did not help. I've tried to uninstall everything of Unity, and I mean everything. I uninstalled and deleted all Unity versions, the hub, and all app/roaming data. The reinstalled Unity. I made an empty project and the error was gone until I made 1 new script and the error reappeared.

Only when I have no scripts in my project the error disappears.

What do I do now? Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what these "empty errors" are? Maybe a screenshot? Do you see them after a fresh install of Unity?

Comment: I added a screenshot. This is after a fresh install of Unity, I even removed everything that Unity uses. I only have 1 script in this empty project and it's a default script.

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.14f1\Editor\Data\Tools\RoslynScripts folder Open the batch file in notepad and paste the following:

```
 @ECHO OFF
 set APPLICATION_CONTENTS=%~dp0..\..
 echo host set to %APPLICATION_CONTENTS%
 "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.2.14f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Roslyn\csc.exe" /shared %*
 exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Found the answer here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1680858/blank-console-error-on-empty-project-with-a-single.html